# What are the correct vertices and indices for a cube using this mesh function?

Tags: c++, opengl, cube, indices, vertices

I'm trying to create a cube using vertices and indices. The vertices I found by plotting it onto a graph, and the indices were carefully patterned and calculated to make two triangles per side of a cube. However, when I turned on the program, a cube did not show, why is this? Are my vertices/indices incorrect? Am I putting in the wrong number of vertices/indices in the `createMesh` function? Or am I doing this all incorrectly?

Function that has indices and vertices.

```cpp
void createObjects() {
    std::vector<GLuint> indices {
        //Top
        0, 1, 2,
        2, 3, 1,

        //Bottom
        4, 5, 6,
        6, 7, 5,

        //Front
        8, 9, 10,
        10, 11, 9,

        //Back
        12, 13, 14,
        14, 15, 13,

        //Left
        16, 17, 18,
        18, 19, 17,

        //Right
        20, 21, 22, 
        22, 23, 21

        /*0, 3, 1,
        1, 3, 2,
        2, 3, 0,
        0, 1, 2*/
    };


    std::vector<GLfloat> vertices {
        //Top
        -1, 1, -1, //0
         1, 1, -1  //1
        -1, 1,  1, //2
         1, 1,  1, //3

        //Bottom
        -1, -1, -1, //4
         1, -1, -1, //5
        -1, -1,  1, //6
         1, -1,  1  //7

        //Front
        -1,  1, 1, //8
         1,  1, 1, //9
        -1, -1, 1, //10
         1, -1, 1, //11

        //Back
        -1,  1, -1, //12
         1,  1, -1, //13
        -1, -1, -1, //14
         1, -1, -1, //15

        //Left
        -1,  1,  1, //16
        -1,  1, -1, //17
        -1, -1,  1, //18
        -1, -1, -1, //19

        //Right
        1,  1,  1, //20
        1,  1, -1, //21
        1, -1,  1, //22
        1, -1, -1  //23



        /*-1, -1, 0,
         0, -1, 1,
         1, -1, 0,
         0,  1, 0*/
    };


    for (std::size_t x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
        meshVector.emplace_back(new Mesh());
        meshVector[x]->createMesh(vertices, indices, 24, 12);
    }
}
```

Create mesh function and draw function

```cpp
void Mesh::createMesh(const std::vector<GLfloat>& vertices, const std::vector<GLuint>& indices, GLuint numOfVertices, GLuint numOfIndices) {
    indexCount = numOfIndices;

    //Binding
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    //Information
    //VBO Information
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(*vertices.data()) * numOfVertices, vertices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    //IBO Information
    glGenBuffers(1, &IBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(*indices.data()) * numOfIndices, indices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);


    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    //Unbinding
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

}

void Mesh::renderMesh() {
    //Binding
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IBO);

    //Rendering
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indexCount, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

    //Unbinding
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(vertices)`  is not what you want, but is the size of an address. You want `3* sizeof(GLfloat)` because each vertex has 3 floats. Same for indices: `3 * sizeof(GLuint)`

Comment: Neither of these changed the outcome, could it be the cube vertices?

Comment: Please, show your `glDraw***` command. Better, some code "around" it.

Comment: @Ripi2 its on the main question now :D

Comment: @Rabbid76 you know what could cause the problem?

Comment: @Rabbid76 nope, still the same ...

Comment: @Rabbid76 could my vertices/indices be wrong ??

Comment: Do you have backface culling enabled?  If culling is causing your triangles to disappear then your winding direction might be backwards.  Another good thign to try is disabling depth testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removed `GLuint numOfVertices/Indices` and replaced `sizeof(*vertices.data()) * numOfVertices` with sizeof(GLuint) * indices.size()`. Finally, replaced the cube vertices and indices with new coordinates

```cpp
std::vector<GLuint> indices {
        //Top
        2, 6, 7,
        2, 3, 7,

        //Bottom
        0, 4, 5,
        0, 1, 5,

        //Left
        0, 2, 6,
        0, 4, 6,

        //Right
        1, 3, 7,
        1, 5, 7,

        //Front
        0, 2, 3,
        0, 1, 3,

        //Back
        4, 6, 7,
        4, 5, 7
    };


    std::vector<GLfloat> vertices {
        -1, -1,  0.5, //0
         1, -1,  0.5, //1
        -1,  1,  0.5, //2
         1,  1,  0.5, //3
        -1, -1, -0.5, //4
         1, -1, -0.5, //5
        -1,  1, -0.5, //6
         1,  1, -0.5  //7
    };
```

That's it.